# Could i echo from a txt file without "type" command?

Tags: batch-file

Could i do something like this without the type command? or with it but i need to store text from a txt file to a %variable% like

```
set thing=type C:\something\code.txt
```

But the problem is that the variable is `"Type C:\something\code.txt"`
not like "hi this is text" from the code.txt
please answer if you know any kind of way to do this thx

example

```
set serialkey=X234-2345
set yourserialkey=type "C:\something\code.txt"
if %yourserialkey%==serialkey goto success
exit
:success
echo hi!
pause
exit
```

Comment: I think the question is unclear and doesn't make much sense unless you illustrate it with an example.

Comment: Check my answer here  - i set output of java command as variable. If you substitute the java call with the type you might get somewhere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640331/sqlserver-connection-with-windows-authentification-in-32-and-64-bit-environment/33805610#33805610

Comment: `set /P "yourserialkey=" <  "C:\something\code.txt"`

Comment: @Aacini Thank you so much!! thats exactly what i was looking for!